# C++ store iterators in a SET

Tags: c++

In my program I have a set: (  `std::set<int> myset;`  ) and after some treatment I finally take one iterator which I have decelerated like this ( `set<int>::iterator findnumb;` ). Well  let say I have to do this 5 times in MYSET, 5 times define differences iterators (it1, it2 ,....it5) and not only this but after that to sort them by the content that they show. My idea it was to create a loop and in every time put the specific iterator in a set and sort but I don't know  how I declare this.

I create an simple example that take for user 5 number and finds the nearest bigger from our set and print it. But in every loop the old iterator replace from the new one and in my real program I want to store this iterator int a set. Well based on this can you modify this example and store the iterators in a set sort by the content that they show.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    std::set<int> myset;
    for (int i=1; i<=20; ++i) 
    {myset.insert(i*10);}


    vector<int> vect;
    int numb;
    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) 
    {
        cout << "give a number" <<endl;
        cin >> numb;
        vect.push_back(numb);
    }

    set<int>::iterator findnumb;
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = vect.begin(); it != vect.end(); ++it)
    {
        findnumb=myset.find(*it);
        while ( (*findnumb)!=(*it))
        { ++(*it); findnumb=myset.find(*it);}
        cout << *findnumb<<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input and expected output? I don't understand your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly.

```
struct dereferenced_less {
    template<typename I>
    bool operator()(const I& lh, const I& rh) const { return *lh < *rh; }
};


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    set<int> myset = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
    vector<int> vect = { 17, 32, 4, 16, 28, 120 };

    set<set<int>::const_iterator, dereferenced_less> findnumbs;
    for (int i : vect)
    {
        auto findnumb = myset.upper_bound(i);
        if (findnumb != end(myset))
            findnumbs.insert(findnumb);
    }

    // findnumbs: {10, 20, 30, 40}
}
```

If you only want the iterators ordered it might be better to sort the input vector and process the set skipping dupklicate elements.

```
    vector<set<int>::const_iterator> result;
    sort(begin(vect), end(vect));

    for (int i : vect)
    {
        auto find = myset.upper_bound(i);
        if (find != end(myset) && (result.empty() || *result.back() != *find))
            result.push_back(find);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sets where you can use vectors.

and this

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = vect.begin(); it != vect.end(); ++it)
```

is **NOT** how you traverse a vector!!! Iterators are made to be used in template algorithms, an on containers that cannot be randomly accessed. This is how you use vectors

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++ i)

vec[i] // the i-th element
```

Or with the new syntax

```
for (int x : vect)

x // the i-th element
```

Also `find` will allways find the element in the set, when not it will return the end iterator, that's after the very last element
so this

```
findnumb=myset.find(*it);
while ( (*findnumb)!=(*it))
{ ++(*it); findnumb=myset.find(*it);}
```

is useless and wrong. To test if find found the element use

```
if (findnumb != myset.end())
```

Of course if all you want to know is whether or not the element is in the set, it's better to use count and forget about the iterators at all.

```
if (myset.count(x) > 0)
```

And don't store iterators if you only want to read the value not write it. Just store the value itself

Answer (score 0):

with the help of hansmaad I found out what I need (baste on my code) thanks a lot.!!!!!!!!!!! Also I have a last question, how I use FIND in set findnumbs!!!! like     set::const_iterator, dereferenced_less>::iterator ithelp;              ithelp=findnumbs.find(20)

```
#

include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>   

struct dereferenced_less {
    template<typename I>
    bool operator()(const I& lh, const I& rh) const { return *lh < *rh; }
};


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    set<int> myset;
    for (int i=1; i<=10; ++i) 
    {myset.insert(i*10);}   
    int vc[] = { 17, 32, 4, 16, 28 };
    vector<int> vect ;
    vect.assign (vc, vc+5);
    set<set<int>::const_iterator, dereferenced_less> findnumbs;
    set<int>::iterator findnumb;
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = vect.begin(); i != vect.end(); ++i)
    { cout << *i << endl; }
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = vect.begin(); i != vect.end(); ++i)
    {
        findnumb = myset.find(*i);
        while ( (*findnumb)!=(*i))
        { ++(*i); findnumb=myset.find(*i);}
            findnumbs.insert(findnumb);
            cout << *findnumb<<" ";
    }

    for (set<set<int>::const_iterator, dereferenced_less>::iterator it=findnumbs.begin(); it!=findnumbs.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *(*it);

  std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```